# SQL: Realm Violation for GRANT on ALTER SESSION

Tags: sql, oracle

New to realms. I have installed an Oracle Database and created a user (USER1).  Trying to grant him permissions, i get this error.

```
SQL> GRANT ALTER SESSION TO USER1;
GRANT ALTER SESSION TO USER1
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-47410: Realm violation for GRANT on ALTER SESSION
```

When i try the suggested solution i get same.

```
SQL> BEGIN
    DVSYS.DBMS_MACADM.CREATE_REALM(
  2    3      realm_name => 'Test_Realm',
  4      description => 'Test',
  5      enabled => DBMS_MACUTL.G_YES,
  6      audit_options => 0);
  7      END;
  8      /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


SQL> BEGIN
    DVSYS.DBMS_MACADM.ADD_OBJECT_TO_REALM(
  2    3      realm_name => 'Test_Realm',
  4      object_owner => 'RAYMONDO',
  5      object_name => 'RAYMONDO',
  6      object_type => 'ROLE');
  7      END;
  8
/  9

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> BEGIN
          DVSYS.DBMS_MACADM.ADD_AUTH_TO_REALM(
  2    3            REALM_NAME => 'Test_Realm',
  4            GRANTEE => 'RAYMONDO',
  5            AUTH_OPTIONS => DVSYS.DBMS_MACUTL.G_REALM_AUTH_OWNER);
  6          END;
  7      /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> GRANT ALTER SESSION TO RAYMONDO;
GRANT ALTER SESSION TO RAYMONDO
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-47410: Realm violation for GRANT on ALTER SESSION
```

So am not sure what is needed

Answer (score 0):

The Database Vault is enabled in the database.

The `table, schema` owning the table and the role to which the privilege is being granted have been added to the same realm that protects the table.

To resolve this step, try to temporarily added the `USER1` user in the realm `'Test_Realm'`:

```
    BEGIN
        DVSYS.DBMS_MACADM.CREATE_REALM(
        realm_name => 'Test_Realm',
        description => 'Test',
        enabled => DBMS_MACUTL.G_YES,
        audit_options => DBMS_MACUTL.G_REALM_AUDIT_FAIL +
DBMS_MACUTL.G_REALM_AUDIT_SUCCESS);
        END;
        /


        BEGIN
        DVSYS.DBMS_MACADM.ADD_OBJECT_TO_REALM(
        realm_name => 'Test_Realm',
        object_owner => 'RAYMONDO',
        object_name => '%',
        object_type => 'ROLE');
        END;

    /

    BEGIN
              DVSYS.DBMS_MACADM.ADD_AUTH_TO_REALM(
              REALM_NAME => 'Test_Realm',
              GRANTEE => 'USER1',
              AUTH_OPTIONS => DVSYS.DBMS_MACUTL.G_REALM_AUTH_OWNER);
            END;
        /
```

After this try to run your `Grant` command:

```
SQL> GRANT ALTER SESSION TO USER1;
```

Once your work is done then `revoke` the temporarily granted access:

```
revoke alter session from USER1;



BEGIN
  DVSYS.DBMS_MACADM.DELETE_AUTH_FROM_REALM(
  REALM_NAME => 'Test_Realm',
  GRANTEE => 'USER1');
END;
/
```

Comment: Same error after i tried this ........SQL> BEGIN
  DVSYS.DBMS_MACADM.ADD_AUTH_TO_REALM(
  2    3    REALM_NAME => 'Database Vault Account Management',
  4    GRANTEE => 'RAYMONDO',
  5    AUTH_OPTIONS => DVSYS.DBMS_MACUTL.G_REALM_AUTH_OWNER);
  6  END;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> grant connect,resource to RAYMONDO;
grant connect,resource to RAYMONDO
*
ERROR at line 1:

Comment: i have edited my answer .....please try to run the begin statements in sequence...in the second begin statement updated the XXX details with yours

Comment: BEGIN
 DVSYS.DBMS_MACADM.ADD_AUTH_TO_REALM(
  realm_name   => 'Test_Realm', 
  grantee      => 'RAYMONDO', 
  auth_options => DBMS_MACUTL.G_REALM_AUTH_PARTICIPANT;
END;

Comment: thats strange...try the above begin, run again your grant statment and let me know

Comment: BEGIN
DVSYS.DBMS_MACADM.ADD_AUTH_TO_REALM(
  2    3      realm_name => 'Test_Realm',
  4      grantee => 'RAYMONDO',
  5      auth_options => DBMS_MACUTL.G_REALM_AUTH_PARTICIPANT);
  6   END;
  7  /
BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-47260: Realm Authorization to Test_Realm for Realm RAYMONDO already defined
ORA-06512: at "DVSYS.DBMS_MACADM", line 1903
ORA-06512: at "DVSYS.DBMS_MACADM", line 1968
ORA-06512: at "DVSYS.DBMS_MACADM", line 1983
ORA-06512: at line 2

Comment: Same issue, tried the grant anyway but of course same output

Comment: ok i have edited begin statment little bit ..please run again all this begin statement in sequence and try again your grant command..

Comment: Maybe the issue is this - the test realm is called RAYMONDO (the username).  See Realm Authorization to Test_Realm for Realm RAYMONDO already defined

Comment: yes you might try with different name its not the issue...not sure if you are running the grant from SYS or which user thats also matter

Comment: Using this user...          sqlplus SYSTEM@orcl

Comment: ohh then try with the Grantee as SYSTEM or SYS